# Can I use Volley with Picasso?

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso

Say I have this method

```
String getURL(){}; // means return a string URL asynchronously
```

`getURL()` uses Volley to request a JSON-object, and GSON parses the object for an image URL.

Could I do this with Picasso?

```
Picasso
    .with()
    .load(getURL())
    .placeholder()
    .into();
```

Will Picasso refresh the place-holder images with the actual images?

Comment: Technical difficulties. But I will try it.

Comment: @the_prole If **getURL()** returns a JSONObject then sorry, you cant use it, but if the getURL() returns a string URL , you can use it.

Comment: so the return type of getUrl() is void yes? You know that load expects a String parameter yes? its just basic computer science here.

Comment: @NigamPatro so basically, I can get an image URL with an asynchronous function, and Picasso will wait for it return a string value?

Comment: @the_prole Picasso will not wait, you need to load the image after getting the image URL only.

Comment: @NigamPatro any suggestion to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It means that inside onResponse of Volley, when you get the Url of the image, you can call Picasso to load that Url into imageview

Comment: @BNK Thank you very much. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @BNK That is a good enough answer for this question. I can checkmark.

Comment: @the_prole Is your are query's about to know, how your getURL method will work with different threads  ..??

Comment: You have posted the answer already :)

Comment: @BNK Sorry I was impatient. If you want to post it, I will check mark it. Mine will take four days before I can check mark it (i know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have known that Volley is asynchronous, so inside `onResponse` of Volley request, where you have succesfully get the Url of the image, you can use Picasso to load that Url into the ImageView.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did actually end up trying this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954019/using-picasso-inside-volley-is-giving-me-a-bad-frame-rate-and-crashing-my-app)

Comment: looks like that your app has issue with memory? Try resizing the images to see if it can fix or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can use Picasso inside Volley's onResponse method.